# Parse string with variables in R

Tags: r, string-parsing

I have a string (say myString) in R like:

```
"(X, Y, other_variable)"
```

and I would like to parse this string into a character vector of length 3, i.e. the same as:

```
c("X", "Y", "other_variable")
```

My best attempt is this:

```
gsub("\\(| |\\)", "", unlist(strsplit(myString, split = ",")))
```

but that seems like a clumsy way to solve this problem.  Is there a better alternative?

Comment: `str_extract_all(x, regex="\\w+")`

Comment: @AvinashRaj you should probably also mention the package name, as this is not a base R function.

Comment: Another option is `scan(text=gsub("[()]+|\\s+", "", x), what ="", sep=",", quiet=TRUE)`

Comment: Another: better to have a real answer than a comment.

Comment: Anyway, you seem to have solved your problem and your way is not clumsy in my opinion. I'd just revert the `gsub` and the `strsplit` part (just change `split=","` with `split=", *"` to get rid of white spaces), but I guess that your solution compares very well with the other proposed in the comments.